# HTML+JS: Set value of <select> in Safari Mobile (ios)

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch-2, mobile-safari

First of all I'm sorry for my poor english

I'm writing  small application with Sencha Touch 2, using "list" component and itemTpl with two html select tags.

There is two the same selects with the same options.

```
<select id="field_0" onChange="function_below_this_code">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="30000">30000</option>
</select>

<select id="field_1" onChange="function_below_this_code">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="30000">30000</option>
</select>
```

in onChange attribute of each select (in one string)

```
x=parseInt(document.getElementById('field_0').value);
y=parseInt(document.getElementById('field_1').value);
if(x > y && y != 0) { document.getElementById('field_0').value = y; }
```

The user SHOULD NOT select value of first field (field_0) higher than second (field_1), so javascript check values for each field, compare it and if first value higher than second it put into first field value of second.

**For example**: (price from [20000] to [10000]) - this is wrong. Script will set value of FROM (first) field to 10000;

It work perfect on my Mac, PC. It's not working well on iPhone.

When I change second field value to "20000" and after that I change first field value to 30000, script won't work and value not became changed to 20000 automatically.

As I sad it work grean on PC and Mac in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

The problem is: code is not working well on safari mobile (ios).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The problem was solved by using setInterval(function(){ my_js_code }, 100);

Comment: I've run into this problem too. Simply `select.value = 'whatever'` after adding options doesn't work like in every other browser in existence. APPLE!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that iOS Safari locks the select option elements during code bound to change event.  Michael Paull from Olson Digital describes the issue here: http://www.olsondigital.com/blog/code/resetting-the-value-of-select-boxes-in-safari-for-ios-onchange and provides a solution that supports all browsers:

```
function resetMySelectBox () {
  $( 'select#mySelectBox option:first' ).prop( 'selected', true );
}

$( 'select#mySelectBox' ).change(function() {
    doSomethingWithData( $( 'select#mySelectBox option:selected' ).val() 
);
    // Calling resetMySelectBox() to reset it in all browsers that will honor it...
    resetMySelectBox();
});

$( 'select#mySelectBox' ).blur(function() {
    // Calling resetMySelectBox() for iOS Safari, which won’t do it onChange and initiates an onBlur after the onChange...
    resetMySelectBox();
});
```

Strangely, this issue arises even when trying to set option values on a different select.  However, the `on.('blur',` solution works in that case as well.